# PHP and JQuery Function Calling Repeated

Tags: php, jquery

I am writing a program that calls a PHP function inside a Jquery script.
The code works for the first time around but when I attempt to use the same PHP again it doesn't work.

Here is the code:

```
$("#left").click(function() {
    $("#Left").text("You chose to go left");
    $("#Right").remove("#Right");
    $("#result").html("<?php left(); ?>");
});

$("#right").click(function() {
    $("#Left").remove("#Left");
    $("#Right").text("You chose to go Right");
    $("#result").html("<?php right(); ?>");
});

$("#fight").click(function() {
    $("#Fight").text("You chose to fight");
    $("#Run").remove("#Run");
});

$("#run").click(function() {
    $("#Fight").remove("#Fight");
    $("#Run").text("You chose to run");
});
```

Left and Right work just fine, but fight and run don't work for someone reason.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: The reason is you are dealing with dynamic elements

Comment: `$("#Right").remove("#Right");` is the same as `$("#Right").remove();`

Comment: That doesn't answer my question

Comment: who is creating those elements.... ie where is it placed

Comment: The elements are being created on the same page through PHP.  i.e I have     <?php function left() { echo "a statement here"; } ?>

Comment: can you share the html sample... also place the script in a dom ready handler and try

Comment: I made a JSFiddler.  It works but it displays the PHP code [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/goznsv6a/)

Comment: instead of copying the PHP code... copy the generated html... ie go to view source in the browser and copy the html and the script

Comment: [JSFiddle Update](http://jsfiddle.net/goznsv6a/2/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91440/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-dexstrum).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is with event delegation change your code like this,

```
$(document).on("click","#left",function() {
    $("#Left").text("You chose to go left");
    $("#Right").remove("#Right");
    $("#result").html("<?php left(); ?>");
});

$(document).on("click","#right",function() {
    $("#Left").remove("#Left");
    $("#Right").text("You chose to go Right");
    $("#result").html("<?php right(); ?>");
});

$(document).on("click","#fight",function() {
    $("#Fight").text("You chose to fight");
    $("#Run").remove("#Run");
});

$(document).on("click","#run",function() {
    $("#Fight").remove("#Fight");
    $("#Run").text("You chose to run");
 });
```

Comment: Works just fine.  Thank you

Comment: we have just changes click function's delegation.. and it shud work

Comment: Works great.  Is there a particular reason my method wasn't working?

Comment: the problem is with delegating the click event. read this, you ll understand better rather than me explaining it,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click